# Azure Web apps missing from VS2013 Server Explorer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Premium and I've installed Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 v 2.5. I'm signed in with my Microsoft Account that also has admin permission in my Azure subscription.

The problem is that I can't see any web apps in the server explorer; I want to try remote debugging. I see a bunch of other Azure artifacts, but no web apps. Service bus and SQL databases lists content I expect. In screenshots I've seen on various MSDN posts, there should be a separate web apps node. I see an App Services node that doesn't list anything. All web apps are listed when I go to manage.windowsazure.com and portal.azure.com.

The App Service node has a context menu that allows me to create a new site. I did that and things got created correctly but nothing is displayed under the node.

This problem exists on both my home machine and work machine; both running a version of Windows 8.1. On my home machine I've re-installed the Azure tools without any effect.

Comment: My server explorer showed Web Apps up until yesterday when I upgraded my Azure Tools from 2.3 to 2.5. I've tried repairing both installations, as well as uninstalling 2.5, then 2.3, and then reinstalling 2.3, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue. Mine is a bit more complicated in that I have multiple subscriptions and the App Service node under Azure is only displaying the app service (web site) for my MSDN subscription but nothing from my corporate subscriptions. Yet all the other nodes like SQL Databases does show the complete list across all subscriptions.

Fixed! I updated the Azure tools to version 2.6 (I had 2.5). I then right-clicked on the Azure node and selected "Manage and Filter Azure Subscriptions". I made sure that all my subscriptions were selected and then clicked the tab "Regions" and made sure all the regions were also selected. I previously had filtered the regions to only North America as I have no intentions of creating a website in Asia...;)

After I saved the changes the Azure node refreshed and all the sites appeared as expected. I think the core issue was the filtering of the regions. Even though all my sites are located in Central-US and that check box was clicked, it wasn't until I removed all filtering for Regions that my sites finally appeared.

Comment: The update to 2.6 and the region filters seem to have done the trick. I can now see the sites under the 'App Services' node

Answer (score 5):

I thought this too, for months. They renamed web sites to web apps, and are still seemingly renaming/moving things around. I just discovered my web site now live in `Azure\App Service\<resource group>` within Server Explorer. I can't see the individual slots, though I don't know or remember if that was possible previously...

Comment: This should be the "accepted" answer, at least for my case.